# How to Build Solr schema for redmine time-entries XML

Tags: xml, solr, redmine

I needed to feed some redmine time entries to solr to make some queries for later visualizations, so I exported the time entries XML using this REST command

```
MyRedmineServerSite/time_entries.xml?limit=1000
```

now if we have this xml document sample:

```
 <time_entry>
   <id>552479</id>
   <project id="195" name="SomeProject"/>
   <issue id="10716"/>
   <user id="58" name="some user"/>
   <activity id="8" name="someTask"/>
   <hours>1.0</hours>
   <comments>some comment</comments>
   <spent_on>2015-02-19</spent_on>
   <created_on>2015-02-19T13:08:23+02:00</created_on>
   <updated_on>2015-02-19T13:08:23+02:00</updated_on>
   <custom_fields type="array">
    <custom_field id="8" name="Billable">
     <value>0</value>
    </custom_field>
   </custom_fields>
 </time_entry>
```

I have searched about creating a schema.xml for the new index for such content and found that it should have poly fields, I have searched about poly fields and seen the currency case but am not sure how to apply it in my case, any help is highly appreciated.